# How to connect NestJS to New Relic?

Tags: logging, nestjs, newrelic, winston

I have some difficulties with NestJS and New Relic connection to collect errors from staging or production.
I am using following npm packages:

- winston
- nest-winston
- newrelic-winston

I can see logs in my console, but do not know how to send errors to the New Relic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Relic LogsInContext enriches the log messages that are output from Winston with additional metadata, but it doesn't forward those logs to New Relic directly. It appears that the Winston configuration is outputting the messages to the console, but you'll want to use a supported log forwarder as described in step 1 at https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/logs/logs-context/configure-logs-context-nodejs/. Our infrastructure agent has Fluentbit bedded and could serve as the log forwarder.

Hope this helps. Let us know if you have anymore questions!